# AWS Lambda Function can import a module when run locally, but not when deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-packaging

I am attempting to expand on [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html), by building a CodePipeline to pick up changes in GitHub, build them, and deploy the changes to my Lambda. `sam build --use-container; sam local start-api` allows me to successfully call the function locally - but when I deploy the function to AWS, the code fails to import a dependency.

My code depends on `requests`. I have duly included that in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
requests==2.20.0
```

My buildspec.yml includes directions to install the dependencies

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - pip install -r hello_world/requirements.txt -t .
      - pip install -U pytest
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - python -m pytest tests/
  build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket <my_bucket>
                                   --output-template-file outputTemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

When my package builds in CodeBuild, that is acknowledged:

```
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:44 Waiting for agent ping 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src775882062/src 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src775882062/src/buildspec.yml 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Processing environment variables 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src775882062/src 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Registering with agent 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Phases found in YAML: 3 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46  PRE_BUILD: 1 commands 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46  BUILD: 1 commands 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46  INSTALL: 2 commands 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Success: true 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Phase context status code:  Message:  
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Entering phase INSTALL 
[Container] 2018/12/27 23:16:46 Running command pip install -r hello_world/requirements.txt -t . 
Collecting requests==2.20.0 (from -r hello_world/requirements.txt (line 1)) 
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/ca/10332a30cb25b627192b4ea272c351bce3ca1091e541245cccbace6051d8/requests-2.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60kB)
...
```

But when I call the deployed function, I get an error:

```
Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'requests'
```

This seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224293/installing-python-dependencies-in-aws-codestar-with-lambda), but I'm not using `PYTHONPATH` in my Lambda building.

---

EDIT: I added some debugging code to files in this package, to try to get a sense of their runtime environment. I also added similar debugging to [another package](https://github.com/scubbo/scubbo-slackbot) that I deploy to Lambda via CodePipeline (though this one doesn't use SAM). Debugging code is below:

```
import os, sys
print('Inside ' + __file__)
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
    if (os.path.exists(path)):
        print(os.listdir(path))
        for f in os.listdir(path):
          if f.startswith('requests'):
            print('Found requests!')
    print()
```

This code attempts to determine if the `requests` module is present in the `sys.path` of the Lambda's runtime environment - and, if so, where.

For this (SAM-enabled) package, `requests` was not found anywhere. In the non-SAM-enabled package, `requests` (as well as all the other `requirements.txt`-declared dependencies of the package) was found in `/var/task`.

It looks like either CodeBuild isn't bundling the dependencies of the function alongside the source, or CloudFormation isn't deploying those dependencies. I suspect that this is something to do with the fact that this is a SAM-defined function, and not a "vanilla" Cloudformation one.

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-deploying.html) says that "You can also use other AWS services that integrate with AWS SAM to automate your deployments", but I can't see how to get CodePipeline to run `sam deploy` instead of `aws cloudformation deploy` (although [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html) claims that they are synonyms).

---

EDIT2 - I believe I've found the problem. For context, recall that I have two packages that are deploying Lambdas via CodePipeline (or attempting to) - the one referred to in this question, which refers to the Lambda as `AWS::Serverless::Function`, and a second, which uses `AWS::Lambda::Function`. The first Function's code was defined as a relative location (i.e., a reference to a directory in my package: `CodeUri: main/`), whereas the second Function's [Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html) was a reference to an S3 location (fetched, in CodePipeline, with `Fn::GetArtifactAtt": ["built", "ObjectKey"]}` or `...BucketName"]}`)

The following is a sample of the first package's CodeBuild output:

```
[Container] 2018/12/30 19:19:48 Running command aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket pop-culture-serverless-bucket --output-template-file outputTemplate.yml 

Uploading to 669099ba3d2258eeb7391ad772bf870d  4222 / 4222.0  (100.00%) 
Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file outputTemplate.yml. 
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template 
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /codebuild/output/src110881899/src/outputTemplate.yml --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>
```

Compare with the same output from the second package's CodeBuild output:

```
....
[Container] 2018/12/30 16:42:27 Running command aws cloudformation package --template-file template.json --s3-bucket {BUCKET_NAME} --output-template-file outputTemplate.yml 

Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file outputTemplate.yml. 
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template 
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /codebuild/output/src282566886/src/outputTemplate.yml --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>
```

This suggests that the first package's `aws cloudformation package` call results in an upload of a file (`669099ba3d2258eeb7391ad772bf870d`) to S3 which is based *only* on the content of the `template.yaml`, whereas the "output" of the Build stage of the second package's CodePipeline is a `zip` of the directory that CodeBuild has been running *in* - which includes the dependencies (because of the calls to `pip install`).

I *could* get around this by simply changing the `template.yaml` of my SAM-template Function to reference an S3 location - but this would mean that I would be unable to test updates to the function locally (with, e.g., `sam local start-api`) without editing the template, since it would reference the S3 location and so wouldn't be affected by local changes.

Ideally, I want to find a way to include the dependencies of the code in the packaged-and-uploaded S3 file. From local testing, it appears that running `sam package`/`aws cloudformation package` without having first run `sam build` results in just the source code (no dependencies) being included. However, I can't run `sam build` in CodeBuild, since SAM isn't installed there.

(This also suggests that I have been unintentionally deploying the test-dependencies of my second package - since it was required to install them in CodeBuild (in order to run tests))

Comment: When deploying a lambda function all the dependencies which are not part of the AWS environment must be added in the deployment package. [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). I do use a command like `pip install requests -t`. It seems to me that CodeBuild depends on the AWS Serverless and it depends on a standard zip file with the lambda. So I think you still have to do it with local installations. But you can put the setup command in the build scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your lambda execution says `"Unable to import module"` when running in the actual AWS Lambda execution environment is because your lambda deployment package (that was uploaded to S3 by `aws cloudformation package` command) is missing required dependencies specified in your *requirements.txt*.

Command like `aws cloudformation package` or `sam package` will work with **AWS::Serverless::Function** resource in your CloudFormation template by zipping all contents (regardless of whether it is source code, dependencies or any other stuff) in a directory specified via `CodeUri` property then it will upload that resulting zip file to S3 bucket giving you a transformed CloudFormation template where the S3 bucket path to your deployment package replaces the path to the source code in your local machine specified in `CodeUri` property.

Looking at your *buildspec.yml*, I think the problem comes from `-t .` option you specified in  `pip install -r hello_world/requirements.txt -t .` command in the **install** phase. This will install dependencies in a current directory (usually the root directory of your project) and not in the directory where the source code of **hello_world** lambda function resides. Thus, the dependencies will not get zipped together with the source code in the later `aws cloudformation package` step.

In general, when you create a lambda function deployment package (whether it's SAM-enabled or plain-old Lambda), you need to bundle everything (source code, dependencies, resources, etc.) that is used in your app. You usually do that by:-

1. Use `sam build` command if it's SAM-enabled CloudFormation template. This command will automatically find your `requirements.txt` and install specified dependencies into the `.aws-sam` directory in preparation for uploading to S3.
2. Manually run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to the right directory where contents get zipped as a deployment package for deploying lambda function. This works in both SAM-enabled or plain-old Lambda CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 1):

I found a "solution" to this, by installing the dependencies of my code in the `main` directory rather than the root directory. However, I believe that a superior option would be to use [layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to hold dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If your `CodeUri` is pointing to `/main`, the content of this folder will be zip and uploaded to S3 when running `aws cloudformation package`, but without the dependencies.

The difference when running `sam package` is that it installs the dependencies from requirements.txt for you and outputs it to `.aws-sam/build/<functionname>` folder.

So, in order to package the dependencies you need to access the function folder and install the dependencies locally, eg.

- `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .`
- then run `aws cloudformation package --s3-bucket <YOUR_BUCKET> --template-file <YOUR TEMPLATE YAML> --output-template-file <OUTPUT TEMPLATE NAME YAML>`.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBuild build environments (specifically when using managed images) are based on Ubuntu base images - these dependencies might not be compatible when running on Lambda. This is because Lambda container environments are based on Amazon Linux - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

You can try fixing this by packaging the dependency in your source bundle and skipping this from your 'requirements.txt' file.

If I'm not wrong a similar issue is addressed at - [Using moviepy, scipy and numpy in amazon lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749806/using-moviepy-scipy-and-numpy-in-amazon-lambda)

Comment: Hi Deepak! Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I don't think that's the solution - I have [another package](https://github.com/scubbo/scubbo-slackbot) that I deploy as a Lambda, which [similarly has a dependency on requests](https://github.com/scubbo/scubbo-slackbot/blob/master/requirements.txt#L2), and that has no problems. I suspect it's because my CodeBuild for that package installs into `lib` rather than `.`. I'll try that, instead.